# Writing a license agreement for my stock footage - where do I start?

Tags: copyright

I have no background in law.

I capture drone footage as a hobby, and want to license it to my local church for use in some of their non-commercial video productions. I want to ensure that they are not allowed to resell it, distribute/share it, use without permission etc etc without obtaining permission from myself.

I am supplying the footage on a hard drive, and am including a copyright notice on the disk (I shall also be drawing their attention to it via email).

What can I do to ensure my footage is covered appropriately? Do I need to write a license agreement? Are you able to point me towards a fully formed license agreement template which I can use? Would it be better to just write an extended copyright notice which details that the footage may not be used without permission?

I am fully aware of the Creative Commons licenses, but these allow the footage to be used by others which is something I want to restrict (almost open-sourcing the footage).

Comment: 1. Which jurisdiction are you in?  2. Are there any lawyers in your local church who could help draft an agreement?

Comment: 1. I am in the UK 2. I suppose that's possible, though is doing some form of license agreement overkill to begin with? Is it sufficient enough to include suitable copyright notice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just wrote it. A licence agreement specifies what they are allowed to do with your copyright material - your question says what you will allow.

Comment: Fair enough! So, just to clarify; your feeling is that a simple statement of permitted usage is fair enough, rather than writing out a 'formal' agreement?